# Why am I getting a NullPointerException in my code?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` each time I try to run the code using another class.

Can some please read through it somehow without running it?  Because you would have to need the pictures.  I just need to know if I did anything wrong, which I probably did since it is giving me this exception.

I really need help I don't know what to do, I've tried many things.

### Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BurgerMakerPanel$TopBreadListener.updateLabel(BurgerMakerPanel.java:174)
    at BurgerMakerPanel.<init>(BurgerMakerPanel.java:40)
    at BurgerMaker.main(BurgerMaker.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
```

### BurgerMaker.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BurgerMaker {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Burger Maker");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(new BurgerMakerPanel());

    frame.pack();


      frame.setVisible(true);
      }


}
```

### BurgerMakerPanel.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BurgerMakerPanel extends JPanel{
  private final int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = 1200;
  private JLabel inputLabel, inputLabel2, inputLabel3, inputLabel4, inputLabel5, inputLabel6, inputLabel7, titleLabel, titleLabel2, topBreadPicture, bottomBreadPicture, 
    pattyPicture, cheesePicture, veggiePicture, saucePicture;
  private JComboBox breadList, breadList2, pattyList, vegetableList, sauceList, cheeseList;
  private JPanel primary, picturePanel, test, test2, test3, test4, titlePanel, spacePanel, topBreadPanel, bottomBreadPanel, pattyPanel, veggiePanel, saucePanel, cheesePanel;
  private JButton push;

  public BurgerMakerPanel() { 
    String[] breadStrings = {"White Bread Top", "Rye Bread Top", "Hamburger Bread Top", "Wheat Bread Top"};
    String[] pattyStrings = {"Beef", "Chicken", "Pork"};
    String[] veggieStrings = {"Lettuce", "Tomato", "Pickle", "Onion"};
    String[] bread2Strings = {"White Bread Bottom", "Rye Bread Bottom", "Hamburger Bread Bottom", "Wheat Bread Bottom"};
    String[] cheeseStrings = {"American", "Swiss Cheese", "Cheddar Cheese", "Pepper Jack Cheese"};
    String[] sauceStrings = {"Mayonnaise", "Mustard", "Ketchup", "BBQ"};

    push = new JButton("Create my Sandwich/Burger!");

    TopBreadListener tbl = new TopBreadListener();
    BottomBreadListener bbl = new BottomBreadListener();
    PattyListener pl = new PattyListener();
    CheeseListener cl = new CheeseListener();
    SauceListener sl = new SauceListener();
    VeggieListener vl = new VeggieListener();

    JLabel separatorLabel = new JLabel("  ________________________________________________________________  " );
    separatorLabel.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel separatorLabel2 = new JLabel("  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  " );
    separatorLabel2.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 14));

    inputLabel = new JLabel("Select your type of bottom bread:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    inputLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    breadList = new JComboBox(breadStrings);
    breadList.setSelectedIndex(3);
    breadList.addActionListener(new TopBreadListener());
    tbl.updateLabel(breadStrings[breadList.getSelectedIndex()]);


    inputLabel2 = new JLabel("Select your type of patty:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    inputLabel2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    pattyList = new JComboBox(pattyStrings);
    pattyList.setSelectedIndex(2);
    pattyList.addActionListener(new PattyListener());
    pl.updateLabel(pattyStrings[pattyList.getSelectedIndex()]);

    inputLabel3 = new JLabel("Select your type of sauce:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    inputLabel3.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    sauceList = new JComboBox(sauceStrings);
    sauceList.setSelectedIndex(3);
    sauceList.addActionListener(new SauceListener());
    sl.updateLabel(sauceStrings[sauceList.getSelectedIndex()]);

    inputLabel4 = new JLabel("Select your type of cheese:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    inputLabel4.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    cheeseList = new JComboBox(cheeseStrings);
    cheeseList.setSelectedIndex(3);
    cheeseList.addActionListener(new CheeseListener());
    cl.updateLabel(cheeseStrings[cheeseList.getSelectedIndex()]);

    inputLabel5 = new JLabel("Select your type of vegetable:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    inputLabel5.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    vegetableList = new JComboBox(veggieStrings);
    vegetableList.setSelectedIndex(3);
    vegetableList.addActionListener(new VeggieListener());
    vl.updateLabel(veggieStrings[vegetableList.getSelectedIndex()]);

    inputLabel6 = new JLabel("Select your type of top bread:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    inputLabel6.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    breadList2 = new JComboBox(bread2Strings);
    breadList2.setSelectedIndex(4);
    breadList2.addActionListener(new BottomBreadListener());
    bbl.updateLabel(bread2Strings[breadList2.getSelectedIndex()]);

    inputLabel7 = new JLabel("Press this only when you are done making your sandwich/burger!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    inputLabel7.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));

    titleLabel = new JLabel("This is a program that will help you make your own sandwich or burger!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    titleLabel2 = new JLabel("Follow all directions and have fun! Thank you!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15));
    titleLabel2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15));

    primary = new JPanel();
    // Set up first subpanel
    picturePanel = new JPanel();
    spacePanel = new JPanel();
    titlePanel = new JPanel();

    topBreadPanel = new JPanel();
    saucePanel = new JPanel();
    pattyPanel = new JPanel();
    cheesePanel = new JPanel();
    veggiePanel = new JPanel();
    bottomBreadPanel = new JPanel();
    topBreadPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 70));
    saucePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 7));
    pattyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 127));
    cheesePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 9));
    veggiePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 58));
    bottomBreadPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 70));

    test = new JPanel();
    test2 = new JPanel();
    test3 = new JPanel();
    test4 = new JPanel();
    titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 60));
    spacePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 5));
    test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 80));
    test2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 80));
    test3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 80));
    test4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 60));
    picturePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Here is your finished product!");

    picturePanel.add(label1);
    picturePanel.add(topBreadPanel);
    picturePanel.add(saucePanel);
    picturePanel.add(pattyPanel);
    picturePanel.add(cheesePanel);
    picturePanel.add(veggiePanel);
    picturePanel.add(bottomBreadPanel);

    titlePanel.add(titleLabel);
    titlePanel.add(titleLabel2);

    test.add(inputLabel);
    test.add(breadList); 

    test.add(inputLabel6);
    test.add(breadList2); 

    test2.add(inputLabel2);
    test2.add(pattyList); 

    test2.add(inputLabel4);
    test2.add(cheeseList);

    test3.add(inputLabel5);
    test3.add(vegetableList);

    test3.add(inputLabel3);
    test3.add(sauceList);

    test4.add(inputLabel7);
    test4.add(push);

    primary.add(spacePanel);
    primary.add(titlePanel);
    primary.add(separatorLabel2);
    primary.add(test);
    primary.add(test2);
    primary.add(test3);
    primary.add(test4);
    primary.add(separatorLabel);
    primary.add(spacePanel);
    primary.add(picturePanel);

    primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
  }
  public JPanel getPanel(){
      return primary;
    }
  private class TopBreadListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      JComboBox ceb1 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
      String ingredientName1 = (String)ceb1.getSelectedItem();
      updateLabel(ingredientName1);
    }
    public void updateLabel(String name) {
      ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");
      topBreadPicture.setIcon(icon1);
    }
  }  
  private class BottomBreadListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      JComboBox ceb2 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
      String ingredientName2 = (String)ceb2.getSelectedItem();
      updateLabel(ingredientName2);
    }
    public void updateLabel(String name) {
      ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");
      bottomBreadPicture.setIcon(icon2);
    }
  }  
  private class PattyListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      JComboBox ceb3 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
      String ingredientName3 = (String)ceb3.getSelectedItem();
      updateLabel(ingredientName3);
    }
    public void updateLabel(String name) {
      ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");
      pattyPicture.setIcon(icon3);
    }
  }  
  private class CheeseListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      JComboBox ceb4 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
      String ingredientName4 = (String)ceb4.getSelectedItem();
      updateLabel(ingredientName4);
    }
    public void updateLabel(String name) {
      ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");
      cheesePicture.setIcon(icon4);
    }
  }  
  private class VeggieListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      JComboBox ceb5 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
      String ingredientName5 = (String)ceb5.getSelectedItem();
      updateLabel(ingredientName5);
    }
    public void updateLabel(String name) {
      ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");
      veggiePicture.setIcon(icon5);
    }
  }
  private class SauceListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      JComboBox ceb6 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
      String ingredientName6 = (String)ceb6.getSelectedItem();
      updateLabel(ingredientName6);
    }
    public void updateLabel(String name) {
      ImageIcon icon6 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");
      saucePicture.setIcon(icon6);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: tell us which line is getting the exception, may be the full exception backtrace

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of your null pointer exception?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at BurgerMakerPanel$TopBreadListener.updateLabel(BurgerMakerPanel.java:174)
 at BurgerMakerPanel.<init>(BurgerMakerPanel.java:40)
 at BurgerMaker.main(BurgerMaker.java:10)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)

Comment: `ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");` Wrong icon name?

Answer (score 3):

`topBreadPicture` is null and is not initialized.

```
topBreadPicture.setIcon(icon1);
```

Comment: I think that the icon has a wrong name, so it's not initialized.

Comment: Don't guess, it is. The OP never initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

The labels such as `veggiePicture` etc. are declared but never instantiated.

As to the images, it would be better to declare them as class attributes and load them at the same time that the labels are (being created &) added.  Further on image loading, use `ImageIO.read(File/URL)` instead of using an `ImageIcon` to load it.  The former will throw an exception if the image is not found, while the latter (AFAIR) will simply return a `null` image.

Answer (score 1):

```
  JComboBox ceb1 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
  String ingredientName1 = (String)ceb1.getSelectedItem();
  updateLabel(ingredientName1);
```

there is potential for ceb1 to be null before calling getSelectedItem()

Answer (score 1):

ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon(name + ".png");
veggiePicture.setIcon(icon5);

veggiePicture is never initializied.

Answer (score -1):

tbl.updateLabel(breadStrings[breadList.getSelectedIndex()]);

breadList.getSelectedIndex() can be -1 if nothing is selected

so breadStrings[-1] would return null therefore trying to pass a null parameter

could be wrong though..

Its still always good practice to check what you're putting as an argument first before passing it in.

Comment: `breadStrings[-1]` would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. `-1` is not a valid array index.